# How do I create stroked path without creating copy by calling cgpathcreatecopybystrokingpath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

As the title says i wonder if it is possible to create a path without creating a copy of it. Basically why I need to do so is because I need a path that I can use CGpathcontainspoint.

```
 CGPathMoveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(cgpath, NULL, newPoint.x, newPoint.y);

    UIBezierPath *tmppath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:cgpath];
    tmppath.lineWidth = 6;
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [tmppath stroke];

    self.containspoint =  [tmppath containsPoint:imaginarynewpos1];
```

This get me the error message: "CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error" Is there something I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you conceptually describe what an alternative would be? Would you modify the existing path to become its stroked counterpart?

Comment: I have a CGmutablepathref that I want to convert into a UIbeizerpath and then stroke it to then check if it intersects with a point. The reason why I want it to be UIBeizerpath is because I got better performance using UIbeizerpath to stroke. I have updated my question if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: Stroking a path like that tries to _draw_ it into the current graphics context, _not_ create a stroked path.

Comment: The two things you are comparing are doing vastly different things.

Comment: So how can I stroke it without drawing it? and should I use Cgcontextcontains point instead or should i even use bitmap data? I think raw image data gives the best performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath()` ***is*** the way to create a path that represents what would be drawn if some other path were stroked (i.e. drawn) with the relevant drawing parameters. Why are you searching for a different way?

There's a need to create a new path because that new path is a *different* path from the original. A path is conceptually a geometric object consisting of "mathematical" lines and curves. Those lines and curves have no width. Line width is conceptually a drawing parameter, not a property of the path. (This is confusing because both `UIBezierPath` and `NSBezierPath` have drawing related properties. Those are just a convenience. The `CGContext` API makes the separation clearer. It would be more consistent but less convenient if line width were set on the current context, like the color is.)

The `cgpath` in your code snippet is a line. The path created by stroking that, assuming either butt or square line cap, would be a rectangle. Those are two very different paths. You have to create the second one to test if a point is within it. Even if there were an API to do what you want directly, the framework would still have to compute the second path behind the scenes to answer the question.